# Determining whether or not a vector is a linear combination of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 5\\
-2 & 1 & -6\\
0 & 2 & 8
\end{bmatrix}
,b= \begin{bmatrix}
2\\
-1\\
6
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The problem asks to determine whether or not vector $b$ is a linear combination of the vectors formed by matrix $A$. I have used the elementary row operations to reduce augmented matrix and got

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 5 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 4 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

I am not sure what to do after this. According to the matrix in reduced row echelon form, the linear system is consistent so there are solutions. The answer in the back of the book states that $b$ is not a linear combination of matrix $A$. I thought that if a matrix in reduced row echelon form was consistent then there existed a linear combination?

Why doesn't $1a_1+1a_2+0a_3=b$ work?

Comment: "The problem asks to determine whether or not vector $b$ is a linear combination of the vectors formed by matrix $A$." Columns or rows? If it's columns, you need to check if $Ax=b$ has a solution. If it's rows, you're interested in $A^Tx=b$.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by columns or rows, I just began this section. From what I understand I am supposed to find the scalars that would make the linear combination possible.

Comment: "Linear combination of the vectors formed by matrix $A$". What vectors are these?

Comment: Once you got the second matrix, is it not clear that $b=2c_1+3c_2?$

Comment: @GitGud I formed matrix A using 3 individual vectors in column 1, 2 and 3. I thought that was the answer but the answer in the back of the book says that there is no such linear combination.

Comment: @mfl How did you get 2 and 3? There is a 5 and 4 in the third column of the matrix.

Comment: Look at the first term of the first column and the first term of $b$ and do the same with the second term of the second column and $b.$ Of course, there are more possibilities, indeed, infinitely many (in this case).

Comment: Oh I see, the third column is the free variable and that gives infinitely many solutions. The 2 and 3 is when the free variable is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three spaces commonly associated with a matrix: [column space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_space), [row space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_space) and [null space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_space).

One solution to the system of linear equations $Ax=b$ is $x=\begin{bmatrix}\color{blue}{2} \\ \color{red}{3} \\ \color{green}{0} \end{bmatrix}$, as can be seen from the given row echelon form.  This implies the solution
$$\require{cancel}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 6\end{bmatrix}}_b=\color{blue}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}+\color{red}{3}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}+\cancel{\color{green}{0}\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ -6 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix}}$$ which could alternatively be found by inspection.  This implies **$b$ is in the column space of $A$**.

We can also see that $(2,-1,6)$ is the negative of the second row of $A$.  This implies **$b$ is in the row space of $A$** (or, perhaps more formally, $b^T$ is not in the row space of $A$).

Converting $A$ to row echelon form $R$ gives
$$
R=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 5 \\
0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $Rx=\mathbf{0}$ has the solution space $\{(-5t,-4t,t):t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ -- this is the null space of $A$.  Since $b$ is not of the form $(-5t,-4t,t)$, we see that **$b$ is not in the null space of $A$**.